# Java maven project, build failing to version mismatch

Tags: java, maven

I have cloned a git repo and am trying to build it locally, but getting the following error

> > [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  0.850 s [INFO] Finished at:
> > 2021-07-12T15:42:57+02:00 [INFO]
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> > org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
> > (default-compile) on project gtvg: Fatal error compiling: invalid
> > flag: --release -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack
> > trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run
> > Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
> > [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
> > please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> > http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I have java jdk 8 and 11 installed, currently using java 8

```
java -version                                                                                                                        

16:03:24
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

and maven

```
 mvn -version   

Apache Maven 3.6.3
```

the pom.xml is really large, so I will post the part which I assume is relevant

```
  <properties>
   <java.version>8</java.version>
   <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
   <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>US-ASCII</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <thymeleaf.version>3.0.12.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
 </properties>


<build>

<resources>

  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
      <include>**/*.html</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  
</resources>

    
<plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
  </plugin>
  
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
```

I had hoped (not sure if I am doing the right thing) changing from 3.8.1

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
```

to 3.6.3

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.6.3</version>
```

could solve my issues. But that doesn't work and end up getting another error

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.3
```

How do i get it to build successfully? I am flexible regarding Java versions. I am allowed to use Java 8 - Java 12, but if possible no changes to the Maven version. It should stay as is 3.6.3

Comment: Could you please show the complete configuration of the maven-compiler-plugin? What command did you use to run Maven?

Comment: Changing the maven-compiler-plugin to 3.8.1 will not change the used java version which is here the problem `invalid flag: --release`. This means you are using JDK8 instead of JDK9+ ... apart from that JDK11 would make sense JDK12 does not because in the meantime superseded by JDK16.0.1 (and in September with JDK17)...

Comment: Furthermore there are things which are not following conventions... The resource configuration in your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise does that mean i need to only change the java version and keep the pom as is?

Comment: You could say I will build only with JDK11 and build with option `--release 8` to keep compatibility...that would work but based on the error you are using JDK8 instead...

Answer (score 0):

You could write one of both 8 or 1.8 into your java version property to declare Java 8. And using Java 8 you can  not use `maven.compiler.release` which could be used only with Java 9+

```
<java.version>8</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

Comment: That will not work because Java 8 does not support `--release` option...

Comment: Ah okay then that one has to be removed.